# Вывод меток по координатам из БД

Tags: mysql, yandex-maps-api

Могу ли я использовать бесплатный АПИ, не нарушая пункт 4 "Условий использования API Яндекс.Карт" https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/terms/index-docpage?from=mapsapi

> Запрещается сохранять или изменять данные, полученные средствами API

если буду выводить карту с метками которые будут строиться по координатам из БД сайта?

То есть, есть табличка в БД, в которой есть поле с координатами, планирую выводить на карте метки по ним, как одну метку на карте, так и несколько меток на одной карте.

Comment: Что-то мешало дать ссылку на правила использования API и процитировать пункт 4? Минус вопросу.

Comment: Вы дольше писали свой коммент, когда могли бы пройти просто по ссылке в топе! Раскидываетесь тут минусами..

Comment: Когда я писал комментарий - никакой ссылки в вопросе не было. Сейчас вы можете говорить "да просто пройдите по ссылке" - но даже её добавили в вопрос не вы, а какой-то [добрый человек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/889346/revisions). Если вам самому вопрос так сильно нужен и так хочется поохать про минуса - ну, в своём праве. Обычно я снимаю минусы когда автор правит вопрос, но в данном случае не вижу никакого смысла. Возможно в будущем это приучит вас сразу писать понятные вопросы, чтобы не приходилось совершать действия по уточнению информации.

Comment: Окей, значит я не заметил что не добавил ссылку, мой косяк! Бывает..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы будете выводить карту с метками которые будут строиться по координатам из БД сайта - то тут нет нарушений ПС.